# Changing font in various places of Orange Book

Tags: fonts, sectioning, legrandorangebook

I'm using the LegrandOrangeBook, which has different fonts for the section headings and Table of Contents than it does for the main text. I do not like this look, and I would like to convert all text in the book to Times New Roman.

My closest guess is to change something in the "Font" section of the Class (.cls) file. Within this file, I can see where they declare the Avantgarde font for headings. I tried to change this to Times New Roman, but nothing seems to have changed:

```
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   FONTS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for inputting international characters
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding for international characters

%\usepackage{avant} % Use the Avantgarde font for headings
\usepackage{times} % Use Times New Roman font for headings

\usepackage{mathptmx} % Use the Adobe Times Roman as the default text font together with math symbols from the Sym­bol, Chancery and Com­puter Modern fonts

\usepackage{microtype} % Improve typography
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to modify the class, that already loads the `mathptmx` package to use  Adobe Times Roman as default text font

All section titles (and more) are defined by the `\sffamily`. The default value can be changed using `\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{\rmdefault}` after the
`\documentclass` declaration.

To write text using the sans serif font use for example `\fontfamily{pag}\fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont` as shown.

[image: a]

And with

```
\chapter{Sectioning Examples}\index{Sectioning}

\section{Section Title}\index{Sectioning!Sections}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\footnote{Footnote example text\ldots Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent porttitor arcu luctus, imperdiet urna iaculis, mattis eros. Pellentesque iaculis odio vel nisl ullamcorper, nec faucibus ipsum molestie.}. Praesent porttitor arcu luctus, imperdiet urna iaculis, mattis eros. Pellentesque iaculis odio vel nisl ullamcorper, nec faucibus ipsum molestie. Sed dictum nisl non aliquet porttitor. Etiam vulputate arcu dignissim, finibus sem et, viverra nisl. Aenean luctus congue massa, ut laoreet metus ornare in. Nunc fermentum nisi imperdiet lectus tincidunt vestibulum at ac elit. Nulla mattis nisl eu malesuada suscipit.

Aliquam arcu turpis, ultrices sed luctus ac, vehicula id metus. Morbi eu feugiat velit, et tempus augue. Proin ac mattis tortor. Donec tincidunt, ante rhoncus luctus semper, arcu lorem lobortis justo, nec convallis ante quam quis lectus. Aenean tincidunt sodales massa, et hendrerit tellus mattis ac. Sed non pretium nibh. Donec cursus maximus luctus. Vivamus lobortis eros et massa porta porttitor.

{\fontfamily{pag}\fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont  Aliquam arcu turpis, ultrices sed luctus ac, vehicula id metus. Morbi eu feugiat velit, et tempus augue. Proin ac mattis tortor. Donec tincidunt, ante rhoncus luctus semper, arcu lorem lobortis justo, nec convallis ante quam quis lectus. Aenean tincidunt sodales massa, et hendrerit tellus mattis ac. Sed non pretium nibh. Donec cursus maximus luctus. Vivamus lobortis eros et massa porta porttitor.}
```

[image: b]