# How to change color for the vertical rectangle in LegrandOrangeBook

Tags: legrandorangebook

Any ideas on how to change the color of this ocre rectangle? I think it can be done in LegrandOrangeBook.cls but I can't find it for the life of me. Thanks.

[image: Vertical Rectangle]

Comment: please see the answer below if it satisfies -- edited from https://www.latextemplates.com/template/legrand-orange-book -- also for changing fonts in the template have a look at this answer -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/651616/changing-font-in-various-places-of-orange-book?rq=1

Comment: In case the answer met your requirements it would be nice to accept by clicking the green check mark on the left and upvoting the answer

Answer (score 1):

[image]

with `red` black combination color

[image]

with `black` color

[image]

originally coded with `ocre!40` color

Go to line 120 onwards in the file named `LegrandOrangeBook.cls`

See the following code line number 124 -- originally this had the color `ocre` -- I have now changed it to `\textcolor{red!70!black!40}` -- now reecompile the file and see the difference in the color of the `Part Number`

```
    \node[anchor=north west, inner sep=0pt, xshift=\Gm@lmargin, yshift=-\Gm@tmargin] at (current page.north west) {\fontsize{220pt}{220pt}\selectfont\sffamily\bfseries\textcolor{red!70!black!40}{#1}}; % Part number
```

The complete set of code lines is below to change and experiment as you want to change anything

```
% Command to create and output the parts pages
\newcommand{\outputpartpage}[2]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \node[anchor=center, rectangle, fill=ocre!20, inner sep=0pt, minimum height=\paperheight, minimum width=\paperwidth] at (current page.center) {}; % Background color
        \node[anchor=north west, inner sep=0pt, xshift=\Gm@lmargin, yshift=-\Gm@tmargin] at (current page.north west) {\fontsize{220pt}{220pt}\selectfont\sffamily\bfseries\textcolor{red!70!black!40}{#1}}; % Part number
        \node[anchor=north east, inner sep=0pt, xshift=-\Gm@rmargin, yshift=-\Gm@tmargin] at (current page.north east) {\fontsize{30pt}{30pt}\selectfont\sffamily\bfseries\textcolor{white}{\strut #2}}; % Part title
        \node[anchor=south east, inner sep=0pt, xshift=-\Gm@rmargin, yshift=\Gm@bmargin] at (current page.south east) { % Mini table of contents
            \parbox[t][][t]{8.5cm}{ % Width of box holding the mini ToC
                \printcontents[part]{l}{0}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}} % Display the mini table of contents showing chapters and sections, change tocdepth to 2 to also show subsections or 0 to only show chapters
            }
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: You are the man. Thanks a lot. It worked.