# How do adjust line recoil/margin of a paragraph in LegrandOrangeBook

Tags: paragraphs, legrandorangebook

The document has always the first paragraph coming with no margin (no recoil). I wanted an uniform look for all paragraphs in the document. Any tips?

[image]

Comment: there was a question posted before by you reference the `LegrandOrangeBook` -- in case you found the answer met your requirement please accept the answer by clicking on the green check mark -- upvoting is also your privilege -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/695187/how-to-change-color-for-the-vertical-rectangle-in-legrandorangebook

Comment: also see -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39228/197451 -- and why no indent in the first para of a section -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39227/no-indent-in-the-first-paragraph-in-a-section

Comment: Hi. The other answer had this little long conversation about having the indent or not, so it was not very straight forward. Only then I noticed that Werner hit the nail with the answer, and it was a little hard to find in that page. Sorry for the confusion, I really should have gone into further examination to this answer. Yes, indeed, this questions is deemed a duplicate for sure. I went to delete it but I got a warning here, so I am leaving as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to experiment

Go to overleaf and open the `LeGrandOrangeBook` project -- on the left find the file named `main.tex`

Go to `Line 131`

```
\section{Section Title}\index{Sectioning!Sections}
```

Compiling this gives the section with no indent in the first paragraph as shown below

[image]

Now add the following lines in the file `main.tex`

```
\section{Section Title}\index{Sectioning!Sections}
     \hangindent2em
      \hangafter=-1
```

Recompiling will give indent in the first paragraph also

[image]

You may like to copy the additional lines in the sub-sections also to indent the first paragraph

**Important**

Do experiment by changing the numeric values to see different outputs -- it will add to your understanding

For example change the -1 to 1 will indent all lines in the first para, except the first line, changing the value to 2 etc will give another output

**EDIT**

To have a generic entry which will add indent in all the section(sub-)

add the following package in the file `main.tex`

```
  \usepackage{indentfirst}
```

reference -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39228/197451

Comment: Thanks js bibra. It worked.